# How to instantiate a marker to a sphere object (GLOBE) in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am beginner in unity ,I Want to put a marker on sphere object to a particular position (by latitude and longitude).     I tried this code :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class testPosLatLong : MonoBehaviour {

public float longi;
public float lati;
public float radius;
public Transform marker;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {
    // longitude and latitude of uae
    longi=23.4241f;
    lati=53.8478f;
    // Transfer to Radians from Degrees
    float templongi = longi * Mathf.PI / 180;
    float templati = lati * Mathf.PI / 180;

    float Xpos = radius * Mathf.Cos(templati) * Mathf.Cos(templongi);
    float Ypos = radius * Mathf.Cos(templati) * Mathf.Sin(templongi);
    float Zpos = radius * Mathf.Sin(templati);

    Debug.Log ("X, Y, Z" + Xpos + " " + Ypos + " " + Zpos);

    // Set the X,Y,Z pos from the long and lat
    Instantiate(marker);
    marker.position = new Vector3 (Xpos, Zpos, Ypos);

    Debug.Log ("Marked  positions: X, Y, Z" + Xpos + " " + Ypos + " " + Zpos);

 }

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {

 }
}
```

This script do I need to drag to my sphere object or camera object ?or create any other Object and drag on it. I do not know how to put a marker on the sphere as i am complete beginner in Unity.

My Sphere is a globe (i added material to the sphere (added earth image ) and made it as a globe object as shown in the screen shot).
After adding the above script to the camera object and when I Play and check the console the  x,y,z position is 0 and can not see any marker on the globe

[my debug log image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jq1P8.png)

I want to add pins to corresponding country and label it .Similar to the globe on this http://kitsdmcc.com/news

[camera object view picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SNF4n.png)

[game object pin view picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yu1ZF.png)

Comment: you instantiated the sphere, but moved the prefab not the one you made.  you need to do something like var newmarker = Instantiate(marker) and then newmarker.position = ...

Comment: Also the c# script where should I attach to the camera object or sphere object ,do u have a sample code , I am just beginner in this unity.

Comment: that was the code

Comment: @BugFinder Can you please help how to add this prefab to the Sphere , I tried what you said but could not see the object on the sphere

Comment: use the scene to debug where it is first.. check where its put it

Comment: See the modified code here  https://www.codepile.net/pile/pNd7vBy2

Comment: @BugFinder  I can see pin object in the scene but from the camera I am not able to see the object, in the scene its outside the sphere object  https://pasteboard.co/IGkWAkm.png

Comment: OK, so, show a picture of where it is from the scene view.. and then we can work out why the camera cant see it, such as its on the far side of the sphere, or, its out of camera view

Comment: @BugFinder here is the picture https://pasteboard.co/IGkWAkm.png

Comment: @BugFinder   here is the picture for the prefab icon is selected  https://pasteboard.co/IGkWAkm.png and this is the camera view when camera is selected : https://pasteboard.co/IGkZCrW.png

Comment: unfortunately looks like our company firewall blocks pasteboard.co

Comment: @BugFinder i added the images in the  question post

Comment: If you moved round the scene it looks like the object is outside the cameras field of view, and not quite where you expected it

Comment: FYI C# != [UnityScript](https://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/UnityScript_versus_JavaScript) (which is a deprecated JavaScript derivative made for Unity).

Answer (score 0):

Hihi, this looks like an interesting project.

To answer your question about where to place the script - you can place it on any object within the scene.
After the objects load in the scene, their attached script will run.

In your case though, it might make sense to place the script on your sphere object.
By doing this, you can reference the sphere object easily, and attach the markers as child objects of the sphere.

As for the marker, I recommend instantiating a prefab.
Create a folder in the Assets folder called "Resources", and place a prefab in there.

You can then use the following code to instantiate the prefab.

```cs
    //The original object, where to instantiate, and the orientation of the new object
    GameObject marker = (GameObject)Resources.Load("markerobject");
    Vector3 location = new Vector3(20,20,20);
    Quaternion rotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,90,0);

    //The object the script is attached to
    GameObject world = this.gameObject;

    //Instantiate the prefab
    Instantiate(marker, location, rotation, world.transform);
```

I've given the instantiated object a set position and orientation, so please use the above code as reference and adjust as needed.

As for the parameters for the **Instantiate** method, you can find the docs here
https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Instantiate.html

Here's a little breakdown of the parameters:

- **1st parameter (Object)**: This is the original object you want to
  instantiate.
- **2nd parameter (Vector3)**: This is the position where the
  instantiated object will appear.
- **3rd parameter (Quaternion)**: This is the orientation of the instantiated object.
- **4th parameter (Transform)**: This will be the parent of the instantiated object. You can ignore this if you don't need to give it a parent.

Comment: I tried this yet I am not able to see the pin in the globe (sphere) this is my c# code https://www.codepile.net/pile/1qYWllXe and this i dragged to to the sphere object

Comment: If the object is correctly instantiated, it should appear in the list of objects in the sample scene on the left hand side. Could you check if the new object is there? If it is, it may have been instantiated inside the sphere object so that we cannot physically see it. In this case, adjust the numbers in the Vector3(20,20,20); part of the code, to a coordinate that lies outside your sphere. Otherwise, please check your console for any errors.

Comment: Yes In the scene I can see the object .But i set x=0.35 y0.35 and z=0.25 but in the play and Game screen I am not able to see the object on the sphere https://pasteboard.co/IGshC0E.png and game screen :https://pasteboard.co/IGshXB2.png

Comment: Good to know it's instantiated somewhere :) When in Play mode, switch the tab from "Game" to "Scene". Then double click on the instantiated object in the left list. This should make the editor zoom and focus on the instantiated object. After that, try zooming out - you might find that it was instantiated in a really far place (for reasons yet unknown).

Comment: I tried what you said , yet my instantiated object (the blue coloured pin ) is not appearing on the camera even though it appears in the scene 
See the camera preview here : https://pasteboard.co/IGt3DrS.png

Comment: I'm going to end the conversation here since you seemed to have moved over the topic of the "prefab not showing issue" in a different post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58833580/